# Merge two arrays into an array of objects with property values

Tags: javascript

Need to generate an array as below:

```
[
  { applicationName :'appName1', frequency:'00'},
  { applicationName :'appName2', frequency:'3'},
  { applicationName :'appName3', frequency:'25'},
  { applicationName :'appName4', frequency:'54'}
]
```

scope.appApplications - it's an object that I am splitting into two arrays.
I have two arrays as below. Need to merge them (applicationName[] and frequencies[]) and come with output as above. How can this be done?

```
var frequencies = [];
var applicationName = [];
angular.forEach(scope.appApplications, function (value, key) {
           frequencies.push(value);
           applications.push(key);
 })
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "JSON object". JSON is like XML. It's a string.

Comment: can you show the structure of $scope.applications?

Comment: Are you saying that frequencies and applicationName are populated by scope.appApplications and then from those two arrays you want to create the desired merged array?

Comment: _Need to generate a JSON as below_ - That is not valid JSON. Try using (for example) https://jsonformatter.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `scope.appApplications` is an object where the keys are the application names and the values are the frequencies, you could do something like:

```
var frequencies = [];
var applicationName = [];
var mergedArray = Object.keys(scope.appApplications).map(function (key) {
  frequencies.push(scope.appApplications[value]);
  applications.push(key);

  return {
    applicationName: key,
    frequency: scope.appApplications[value]
  };
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), you can do this as a single chained functional call:

```
_.zip(applicationName,frequencies).map(function(pair) { 
    return _.object(["applicationName","frequency"],pair); 
});
```

`_.zip()` turns `['a','b','c']` and `[1,2,3]` into `[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]]`.

`Array.map()` calls a function on each member of an array and returns an array of the results.

`_.object()` turns `["applicationName","frequency"]` and `['a',1]` into `{applicationName: 'a', frequency: 1}`.

Comment: This, or its equivalent in lodash, is how I'd do it. +1.

Comment: Note that since lodash v0.4.0 it is now zipObject https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject

Answer (score 2):

You can have an another variable (say targetJson) which will hold your target json. something like this.

```
var frequencies = [];
var applicationName = [];
var targetJson = [];
angular.forEach(scope.appApplications, function (value, key) {
           frequencies.push(value);
           applications.push(key);
           targetJson.push({applicationName :key, frequency:value});
 })
```

Comment: JSON is a string.