# Create two arrays from a collection of object property and values with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, lodash

I have an array that contains objects, like this:

```
[{
 "first" : 1
},
{
 "second" : 2
},
{
 "third" : 3
}]
```

I want to turn this into two arrays, with indexes matching based on these values, such as:

```
["first","second","third"]
[1,2,3]
```

I can iterate through this and get the object keys and values, but I feel there's gotta be a slick way in lodash to do this, that I don't know of.  Any suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: Each item in your array is a different shape. I suspect a different structure would better suit your needs if you are doing operations such as this. For instance, an array of tuples may be better: `[['first', 1], ['second', 2], ['third', 3]]`

Comment: Well, it's for a charting library, which uses this structure for labels and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a non-lodash solution:

```
var arr = [{"first" : 1},{"second" : 2},{"third" : 3}];
var keys = arr.map(function(el){return Object.keys(el)[0];});
var vals = arr.map(function(el){return el[Object.keys(el)[0]];});
```

For the opposite problem (multiple arrays into one array of objects), see [Merge two arrays into an array of objects with property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879006/merge-two-arrays-into-an-array-of-objects-with-property-values)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you just need to map over the object and call [keys()](https://lodash.com/docs#keys) and [values()](https://lodash.com/docs#values)

You will get the first array like:

```
var items = [{a: "1"},{b: "blah",c: "what"},{d: "3"}]
keys = _(items).map(_.keys).flatten().value()
```

returns `["a","b","c","d"]`

And the second array like:

```
values = _(items).map(_.values).flatten().value()
```

returns `["1","blah","what","3"]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your object shape is always `{"label": value}`, then you can use this vanilla JavaScript:

```
var data = [{"first" : 1},{"second" : 2},{"third" : 3}];
var labels = data.map(function(entry) {
    return Object.keys(entry)[0];
});
var values = data.map(function(entry) {
    return entry[Object.keys(entry)[0]];
});
```

---

Your data structure seems sub-optimal based on your comments. I would recommend an alternate structure:

```
var data = [
    {'label': 'first', 'value': 1},
    {'label': 'second', 'value': 2},
    {'label': 'third', 'value': 3}
]
```

Which is then trivial to pick out the labels and values into separate pieces in normal JavaScript:

```
var labels = data.map(function(entry) {
    return entry.label;
});
var values = data.map(function(entry) {
    return entry.value;
});
```

Or if you really want to use lodash:

```
var labels = _.pluck(data, 'label');
var values = _.pluck(data, 'value');
```

Hopefully you can see that this revised structure makes the JavaScript much simpler whether you use lodash or not.