# How to combine two arrays into an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays and I want to form an array of objects such that the new array of obj has two keys with first key being filled with elements of first array and second key having arrays elements of second array. Can this be done using the map function. I found the closest answer as this:-
[Merge two arrays into an array of objects with property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879006/merge-two-arrays-into-an-array-of-objects-with-property-values)

eg.:-

```
ar1=[];
ar2=[];
armixed=[{ar1element,ar2element},{}......]
```

But it uses angular JS I just want to use pure JS.

Comment: We need to see the 2 arrays you're working with, and the end result of what you want them to be, plus possibly the code you've already attempted to use.

Comment: The question you are referring to has the answer - in plain JS ...

Comment: `Can this be done using the map function`? Already answered with map in referrer question.

Comment: Hi there. I see you've just edited your question with some code, which is good, but the code you've provided doesn't give any real clue as to what you're trying to accomplish. Have a look at how to write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In addition, the question you linked doesn't seem to have anything to do with Angular, and in any case merging arrays would be accomplished using "pure" JS even if it were. Can you explain what threw you off there?

Comment: I am gettingscope is undefined

Comment: and that is written in angular

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure what your output should be but the one you provided seems invalid. I have modified the output format to be valid.

For the task you have the solution is to `zip` the arrays, however, JS has no inbuilt `zip` function, so we can emulate it via `map` function:

```js
var ar1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'];
var ar2 = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5'];
var armixed = ar1.map(function(x, i) {
  return [x, ar2[i]]
});

console.log(armixed);
```

Output will be:

```
armixed = [
    ["a1", "b1"]
    ["a2", "b2"]
    ["a3", "b3"]
    ["a4", "b4"]
    ["a5", "b5"]
]
```

If you want objects in your output (rather than arrays), you can just edit the return statement above to something like:

```
return { categories: x, catid: ar2[i] }
```

Comment: how to assign some keys ..like first element will be called as categories suppose and all the second elements will be called catid

Comment: Just edit the return statement to something like: 
`return { categories: x, catid: ar2[i] }`

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays we can write this to make an array of objects from multiple arrays

```js
const price = ['100', '200', '300', '400', '500'];
const qty = ['50', '40', '30', '20', '10'];

const result = price.map((price,i) => ({price, qty:qty[i]}))

console.log(result)
```